# Adding Tittle in tumblr blog with jquery

Tags: jquery, tumblr

I recently discovered tumblr and I decided to create a blog there to promote my website.

Everything seems OK but I only have one problem. In tumblr video and photo posts can't have a title. So when you post a photo the text you add bellow it as caption looks the same.

What I want to do is to replace the first paragraph of each caption with an h3 tag. 
The html structure is something like that

```
<div id="content">
    <div>
        <div>
            <div class="video">
                <div class="caption">Text here</div>
            </div>
            <div class="photo">
                <div class="caption">Text here</div>
            </div>
            <div class="text">
                <h1>Title</h1>
                <div class="caption">Text here</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I tried to to it myself and what I understand till now is that I need to use each() append() to target the first child of each caption but I cant't figure out how to put them together.
What I want is the first paragraph in each caption to be replaced with  tags.

Also as you might noticed text posts use the same class name in my theme as videos and photos but they do have titles. So I don't want to change the first paragraph there. Can I add a second class for example `class="caption photovideo"` and have jQuery target those only. I guess I can the question is how :P.

If you want to check the exact html code of the theme I use here is the link `http://effectortheme.tumblr.com/`

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by replacing the first paragraph with tags? As for trying to target and change the first paragraph, you could trying using the :first-child and :before css selectors maybe? Something like

```
.video p:first-child:before {
    content: "";
}
```